# Best practice method for $http loading popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm pretty new to Angular but I'd like to know if A) the following scenario is possible and B) some leads to documentation on where to get started.

**The scenario:**
Currently in my MEAN app there's a 'loading...' popup that's controlled by jQuery and is faded in at the start of $http requests and faded out after the $http request is successful.

**The goal:** Rather than mixing jQuery in with Angular I think there's probably a better way to do it using just Angular so I'm not mixing the two together. I'd also like to be able to define the text that's displayed in the popup from within the call to show/hide the popup. ie. "Saving new user...", "Deleting user...".

This is relatively straight forward in jQuery but what's the best-practise Angular-method to approach this situation? I'm guessing I'd create a custom module? (maybe?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few Angular best practices to follow here would be:

- Use services to maintain state and share data
- Use directives for view component encapsulation
- Avoid DOM manipulation through imperative styled scripting

A solution which follows these criteria might include...

#### A [value](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#value-recipe) service which holds the loading status and message

```
.value('Loading', {message: '', status: false})
```

#### A [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) which conditionally displays the loading message

**JS:**

```
.directive('loading', function(Loading){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.loading = Loading;
    },
    template: '<div ng-show="loading.status">Loading: {{loading.message}} ...'
  }
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div loading></div>
```

#### An [$http interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#interceptors) to trigger displaying of the directive

```
.config(function($provide, $httpProvider){
  $provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, Loading) {
    return {

      'request': function(...) { 
        Loading.status = true;
        ...
      },


      'response': function(...) {
        Loading.status = false;
        ...
      },

     'responseError': function(...) {
        Loading.status = false;
        ...
      }
    };
  });

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
})
```

Using these components in this configuration, whenever a request is made via $http, requests and responses will be intercepted. On request, the loading status indicator will toggled along with whatever is currently set as the message in the loading service. Once a response (success or failure) resolves, the indicator will be switched off.

An example of an $http request would look look this, from a controller in this case:

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http, Loading){
  $scope.getSomething = function(){
    Loading.message = 'getting something from server';
    $http.get('http://filltext.com/?rows=10&delay=3');
  };
})
```

**Note:** you would need to set Loading.message previous to *all* $http requests to avoid having inaccurate messages appear.

[Demo for proof of concept](http://plnkr.co/edit/5EJ6bKYdEqV9rbmP4ntL?p=preview)

Comment: This is absolutely perfect and much more than I expected to receive, thanks so much!

Comment: Quick question: i've copied / pasted what you have done exactly to see if I was getting the same issue (which I am) and that is that the loading status doesn't appear to be changing the visible status of the loading div?

Comment: Edit: I've got it working on $http requests that are triggered via functions/buttons but on my initial $http.get that occurs on page load, the loading div doesn't show?

Comment: Where is that .get called from? The controller?

Comment: Yeah, it's being called from the controller

Comment: Seems to work in the demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/5EJ6bKYdEqV9rbmP4ntL?p=preview Feel free to contact me privately if you can demonstrate the problem in a Plunker or somewhere else where I can look at the code.

Answer (score 2):

You need [$http interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http).

Also, there is an [angular-loading-bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar) module which you can use in your application or you can look at the code in look into [github](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar/blob/master/src/loading-bar.js) .